# Efficient way to store html in json

Tags: python, html, json, storing-data

I scraped a few thousand URL with Python *Requests* and saved their html content in a json file like so:

```
[
        {"url": "https//someurl.com",
        "html": "<strong>Hello World!<\/strong>"
        },

        {"url": "https//anotherurl.com",
        "html": "<h1>Goodbye World!<\/h1>"
        }
]
```

I end up with a file which weights more than 2.3 gb (since these are actual webpages with large html content).

I used the *htmlmin* lib but it didn't help that much.

I can't use a database for now. So I'm looking for a way to store these very large strings much more efficiently, if possible in a json.

Later down the road, the html will have to be retrieved for processing.

I've been thinking of splitting each dictionary in individual json files. I could for each file generate a random key (to be stored in a json file), name each json file containing `{"url": "https//someurl.com", "html": "<strong>Hello World!<\/strong>"}` after it. This way I could avoid having to iterate through a huge single file to retrieve the right html string. That still doesn't help with the size of file though.

But it would be nice if I could keep everything in a single file. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

## Using Files

What if you generated a unique ID for each unique URL, and store the HTML content in a `.zip` or `.gz` file with the unique ID as the file name.

Inside the JSON file you could then simply just store the ID pointing to the file with the HTML content.

## Using a Database

Certain database/data warehousing system like, [Google's BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) are very efficient in reading large datasets.

If you could store your scraped output in a system like that, the time to find something in your data would reduce dramatically, even for large data sets like yours.